# How do I extact max n values for multiple criteria from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe created from the dictionary below -

```py
d = {
'Region':[
 'north','north','north','north','south',
 'south','south','east','east','east',
 'east','west','west','west'
], 
'Store No':[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
'Sales':[196, 193, 176, 168, 165, 163, 166, 135, 151, 108, 119, 176, 132, 107]
}
```

1) How do I create another dataframe to extract the top 3 stores ("Sales" column) for each region.
2) Assuming the "Regions" column had many more different values (such as Northeast, Northwest,Southwest,etc), how do I create another dataframe to extract the regions that start with "North".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `nlargest` functions.

1) Top 3 sales per region:

You can create a `dictionary` of dataframes, one for each region with top 3 sales:

```
In [687]: top_3_sales = df.groupby('Region')['Sales'].nlargest(3).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'Store No'})  

In [688]: list_of_regions = df.Region.unique().tolist()

In [691]: dict_of_region_df = {region: top_3_sales.loc[top_3_sales['Region'] == region] for region in list_of_regions}
```

Then query your dict to have individual dataframes:

```
In [693]: dict_of_region_df['north']
Out[693]: 
  Region  Store No  Sales
3  north        0    196
4  north        1    193
5  north        2    176

In [694]: dict_of_region_df['east']
Out[694]: 
  Region  Store No  Sales
0   east        8    151
1   east        7    135
2   east       10    119
```

2.) Regions with `north`:

```
In [681]: df[df.Region.str.startswith('north')]
Out[681]: 
  Region  Store No  Sales
0  north         1    196
1  north         2    193
2  north         3    176
3  north         4    168
```

Answer (score 3):

For question 1, use the [nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) function on `dataframe`.

```
    In [13]: df_1 = d.groupby('Region')['Sales'].nlargest(3)

In [14]: df_1
Out[14]:
Region
east    8     151
        7     135
        10    119
north   0     196
        1     193
        2     176
south   6     166
        4     165
        5     163
west    11    176
        12    132
        13    107
Name: Sales, dtype: int64
```

2. For second question, you can use the `startswith` for find region starting with north.

```py
In [11]: df_2 = d[d['Region'].str.startswith('north')]

In [12]: df_2
Out[12]:
  Region  Store No  Sales
0  north         1    196
1  north         2    193
2  north         3    176
3  north         4    168
```